# UITableView: moving rows around in editing mode

Tags: iphone

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if(row == 0)
        return NO;
    return YES;
}

My problem is: although i specified NO for row 0. If I attempt to drag row 1 to replace row 0, the animation lets this happen anyways. The problem is that the above method only decides whether or not there is a move icon on the right of the row. Any ideas on how to stop row 0 from ever getting replaced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

from the `UITableViewDelegate`.

You can do something like this:

```
if ([proposedDestinationIndexPath row] > 0) {
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}

NSIndexPath *betterIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
return betterIndexPath;
```

(From "iPhone Programming" by Joe Conway & Aaron Hillegass)